# JsPlumb endpoints overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsplumb

Suppose I have an element with 4 endpoints, each endpoint has one connection. I need show all connections in endpoint label and remove any by clicking on it's name. Do jsPlumb have this ability from the box? Or how can I do this?
[image]

```
sourceEndpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(requirementSelector), {overlays: removeLabel, maxConnections: -1, endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 4}], anchors: ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"]});
    targetEndpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(solutionSelector), {overlays: removeLabel,maxConnections: -1, endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 4}], anchors: ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"]});

    jsPlumb.connect({
        source: sourceEndpoint, 
        target: targetEndpoint 
    });

    targetEndpoint.bind("click", function(endpoint) {
      var elementEndpoints = jsPlumb.selectEndpoints({element: endpoint.elementId});

      var ids="<div style='border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; background-color: #ffffff'; z-index:10;>";

      elementEndpoints.each(function(ep){
        ids += "<p ng-click='clicked()'>Remove - " + ep.id + "</p>"
      });

      ids += "</div>";

      endpoint.setLabel(ids);
      endpoint.showOverlay();
    });
```

Comment: jsPlumb has connection label but not endpoint label. Do you want to delete connection on single or double clicking on it ? if so it's possible.

Comment: I can get all endpoints from element. Each endpoint has a connection. Now i need display it in endpoint overlay(label)(suppose 4 connections) and remove any by click on it

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you, can you picture it and post an image.

Comment: For example solutions container. By clicking on label "Remove - ep42" I need to remove connection ep_42

Comment: Do you need that label to remove the connection ? If so why don't you bind some event to connection and remove it when it is triggered.

Comment: I can subscribe to click event of label but I can't get access to needed connection. + I use angularjs and ng-click doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44943/discussion-between-maxd-and-pruthvi-bharadwaj)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. When ever new connection is created, bind an event to remove the connection:

```
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(ci) {
            ci.connection.bind("click",function(con){
                jsPlumb.detach(con);
            });
        });
```

Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: Pruthvi Bharadwaj, thanks! but your example doesn't work in my case. One element can have a lot of endpoints and user can see only the last endpoint(see requirement). That is why I need some popup or label to show all connected element and remove selected.